# How does Spark SQL implement the group by aggregate

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, apache-flink

How does Spark SQL implement the group by aggregate? I want to group by name field and based on the latest data to get the latest salary. How to write the SQL

The data is:

```
   +-------+------|+---------|
// | name  |salary|date      |
// +-------+------|+---------|
// |AA     |  3000|2022-01   |
// |AA     |  4500|2022-02   |
// |BB     |  3500|2022-01   |
// |BB     |  4000|2022-02   |
// +-------+------+----------|
```

The expected result is:

```
   +-------+------|
// | name  |salary|
// +-------+------|
// |AA     |  4500|
// |BB     |  4000|
// +-------+------+
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the dataframe is registered as a temporary view named `tmp`, first use the `row_number` windowing function for each group (`name`) in reverse order by `date` Assign the line number (`rn`), and then take all the lines with `rn=1`.

```
sql = """
    select name, salary from
        (select *, row_number() over (partition by name order by date desc) as rn
        from tmp)
    where rn = 1
"""
df = spark.sql(sql)
df.show(truncate=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

1. First convert your string to a date.
2. Covert the date to an UNixTimestamp.(number representation of a date, so you can use Max)
3. User "First" as an aggregate
   function that retrieves a value of your aggregate results. (The first results, so if there is a date tie, it could pull either one.)

:

```
simpleData = [("James","Sales","NY",90000,34,'2022-02-01'),
    ("Michael","Sales","NY",86000,56,'2022-02-01'),
    ("Robert","Sales","CA",81000,30,'2022-02-01'),
    ("Maria","Finance","CA",90000,24,'2022-02-01'),
    ("Raman","Finance","CA",99000,40,'2022-03-01'),
    ("Scott","Finance","NY",83000,36,'2022-04-01'),
    ("Jen","Finance","NY",79000,53,'2022-04-01'),
    ("Jeff","Marketing","CA",80000,25,'2022-04-01'),
    ("Kumar","Marketing","NY",91000,50,'2022-05-01')
  ]

schema = ["employee_name","name","state","salary","age","updated"]
df = spark.createDataFrame(data=simpleData, schema = schema)
df.printSchema()
df.show(truncate=False)
df.withColumn(
  "dateUpdated", 
  unix_timestamp(
    to_date(
      col("updated") ,
      "yyyy-MM-dd"
    )
  ) 
).groupBy("name")
 .agg( 
   max("dateUpdated"), 
   first("salary").alias("Salary") 
 ).show()
+---------+----------------+------+
|     name|max(dateUpdated)|Salary|
+---------+----------------+------+
|    Sales|      1643691600| 90000|
|  Finance|      1648785600| 90000|
|Marketing|      1651377600| 80000|
+---------+----------------+------+
```

Answer (score 0):

My usual trick is to "zip" `date` and `salary` together (depends on what do you want to sort first)

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

(df
    .groupBy('name')
    .agg(F.max(F.array('date', 'salary')).alias('max_date_salary'))
    .withColumn('max_salary', F.col('max_date_salary')[1])
    .show()
)

+----+---------------+----------+
|name|max_date_salary|max_salary|
+----+---------------+----------+
|  AA|[2022-02, 4500]|      4500|
|  BB|[2022-02, 4000]|      4000|
+----+---------------+----------+
```